# Barra de desplazamiento

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero poner una barra de desplazamiento tanto a la derecha como en la parte inferior se que tengo que poner un `JScrollPane` pero no sé en donde lo pondría ni cómo.

Este es el código:

```
package bonos1;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Tabla {


    private JTable t;
    private DefaultTableModel m;
    private int i=0;
    private int a=0;

    public Tabla(){
        //* Inicializar variables *//
        JFrame v = new JFrame();
        m = new DefaultTableModel();
        t = new JTable(m);
        JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(t);

        //* Se agregarn tres columnas inicialmente //*
        m.addColumn("Desarrollo Social");
        m.addColumn("Recursos materiales");
        m.addColumn("Des.agropecuario");
        m.addColumn("Desarrollo economico");
        m.addColumn("Educacion y cultura");
        m.addColumn("Seguridad Publica");
        m.addColumn(" DIF");
        m.addColumn("Secretaria general");
        m.addColumn("Archivo");
        m.addColumn("Registro de lo familiar");
        m.addColumn("Catastro");
        m.addColumn("Turismo");
        m.addColumn("Transparencia");
        m.addColumn("Informatica");
        m.addColumn("Teseroria");
        m.addColumn("Contraloria");
        m.addColumn("Conciliacion Municipal");
        m.addColumn("Oficialia mayor");
        m.addColumn("Servicios generales");
        m.addColumn("Ecologia");
        m.addColumn("Reaglamentos y Espect");
        m.addColumn("Obras publicas");
        m.addColumn("Planeacion");
        m.addColumn("Unidad juridica");
        m.addColumn("Comunicacion social");
        m.addColumn("IMDM");
        m.addColumn("IMJUV");
        m.addColumn("COMUDE");
        m.addColumn("Poteccion civil");


        /** Se agregan diez columnas inicialmente con el valor del contador **/

        /** Se agregan el scroll a la ventna **/
        v.getContentPane().add(s,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel pN=new JPanel();

        //* Inicializan botonnes y se dan acciones *//
        JButton aF = new JButton("Agregar Fila");
        pN.add(aF);
        aF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                agregar(2);
            }
        });

        JButton bF = new JButton("Borrar Fila");
        pN.add(bF);
        bF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                eliminar(2);
            }
        });


        /** Agregan y se crea ventana **/
        v.getContentPane().add(pN,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        v.pack();
        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        v.setVisible(true);
    }

    /* Se encarga de eliminar
     * si el valor es 1 elimina la columna
     * si el valor es 2 elimina la fila */
    private void eliminar(int caso){
        try{
            switch(caso){
                case 1:
                    t.removeColumn(t.getColumnModel().getColumn(t.getSelectedColumn()));//Elimna la columna selecionada por el usuario
                    break;
                case 2:
                    m.removeRow(t.getSelectedRow());//Elimna la fila selecionada por el usuario
                    break;
            }
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aIE){}
    }

    /* Se encarga de agregar
     * si el valor es 1 agrega una columna
     * si el valor es 2 agrega una fila */
    private void agregar(int caso){
        try{
            switch(caso){
                case 2:
                    m.addRow(new Object[]{a++,"",""});//Agrega un fila con el valor del contador y los demas en blanco
                    break;
            }
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aIE){}
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Tabla();//Se corre la clase
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Aunque la pregunta está correctamente formulada, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Saludos, Nataly.

Todo lo que has hecho parece estar bien (ya has agregado el `JScrollPane`), lo único que te hace falta es mostrar las barras de desplazamiento.

Por defecto, la clase `JScrollPane` muestra las barras de desplazamiento **cuando se necesiten**, es decir, cuando agregues muchas filas (y estas ya no quepan en el `JScrollPane`)  la barra aparecerá automáticamente.

Lo único que debes hacer es agregar estos métodos después declarar tu `JScrollPane`:

```
JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(t);
s.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
s.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Las barras de desplazamiento pueden tener 3 tipos de "táctica" o "norma" de cómo deben aparecer. En el caso de la barra vertical:

```
JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS // Mostrará la barra SIEMPRE
JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED // Se mostrara si se necesita (por defecto)
JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER // Nunca se mostrará (aunque los elementos no quepan)
```

Y en el caso de la barra horizontal igual:

```
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS // Mostrará la barra SIEMPRE
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED // Se mostrara si se necesita (por defecto)
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER // Nunca se mostrará (aunque los elementos no quepan)
```

En el caso de la barra de desplazamiento HORIZONTAL, aún si lo ajustas a que aparezca siempre realmente no tendrá ningún efecto, ya que la `JTable` por defecto auto-ajusta todas las columnas para que quepan en el tamaño del `JScrollPane`. Te recomendaría hacer lo siguiente:

```
t = new JTable(m);
t.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

El método `setAutoResizeMode` cambia la forma en que se deben auto-ajustar las columnas. Por defecto, la clase `JTable` utiliza un "auto-ajuste a todas las columnas", al utilizar `JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` le indicamos a la `JTable` que no las ajuste para que quepan, sino que se estiren (lo que forzaría a aparecer la barra horizontal de desplazamiento).

Adjunto el resultado:

[image: gif]

Comment: Funciona perfecto, ¡muchas gracias!