# Alguien podría orientarme con la barra de desplazamiento de Eclipse?

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo un problema al momento de ejecutar me sale como en la foto[image: La barra de desplazamiento aparece en la parte inferior , necesito que al ejecutarlo aparezca en la parte superior]
La barra de desplazamiento aparece en la parte inferior , necesito que al ejecutarlo aparezca en la parte superior
Hay algún código para añadir y modificar eso?

CODIGO:

```
public class DlgListarCocina extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
 
    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea txtS;
    private JButton btnCerrar;
    private JButton btnListar;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
 
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DlgListarCocina dialog = new DlgListarCocina();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public DlgListarCocina() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\NUEVO ICONO.png"));
        setTitle("Listado de cocinas");
        setBounds(100, 100, 535, 437);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);
 
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 504, 293);
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane);
 
        txtS = new JTextArea();
        txtS.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtS);
 
        btnCerrar = new JButton("Cerrar");
        btnCerrar.addActionListener(this);
        btnCerrar.setBounds(161, 338, 89, 23);
        contentPanel.add(btnCerrar);
 
        btnListar = new JButton("Listar");
        btnListar.addActionListener(this);
        btnListar.setBounds(270, 338, 89, 23);
        contentPanel.add(btnListar);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnListar) {
            actionPerformedBtnListar(e);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == btnCerrar) {
            actionPerformedBtnCerrar(e);
        }
    }
    protected void actionPerformedBtnCerrar(ActionEvent e) {
        dispose();
    }
    protected void actionPerformedBtnListar(ActionEvent e) {
        mostrarListado();
 
    }
 
    private void mostrarListado() {
        txtS.setText("LISTADO DE COCINAS \n\n");
        imprimir("Modelo    : "+FrmPrincipal.modelo0);
        imprimir("Precio    : S/. "+FrmPrincipal.precio0);
        imprimir("Profundidad   : "+FrmPrincipal.fondo0+" cm");
        imprimir("Ancho     : "+FrmPrincipal.ancho0+" cm");
        imprimir("Alto  : "+FrmPrincipal.alto0+" cm");
        imprimir("Quemadores    : "+FrmPrincipal.quemadores0);
        imprimir("");
        imprimir("Modelo    : "+FrmPrincipal.modelo1);
        imprimir("Precio    : S/. "+FrmPrincipal.precio1);
        imprimir("Profundidad   : "+FrmPrincipal.fondo1+" cm");
        imprimir("Ancho     : "+FrmPrincipal.ancho1+" cm");
        imprimir("Alto  : "+FrmPrincipal.alto1+" cm");
        imprimir("Quemadores    : "+FrmPrincipal.quemadores1);
        imprimir("");
        imprimir("Modelo    : "+FrmPrincipal.modelo2);
        imprimir("Precio    : S/. "+FrmPrincipal.precio2);
        imprimir("Profundidad   : "+FrmPrincipal.fondo2+" cm");
        imprimir("Ancho     : "+FrmPrincipal.ancho2+" cm");
        imprimir("Alto  : "+FrmPrincipal.alto2+" cm");
        imprimir("Quemadores    : "+FrmPrincipal.quemadores2);
        imprimir("");
        imprimir("Modelo    : "+FrmPrincipal.modelo3);
        imprimir("Precio    : S/. "+FrmPrincipal.precio3);
        imprimir("Profundidad   : "+FrmPrincipal.fondo3+" cm");
        imprimir("Ancho     : "+FrmPrincipal.ancho3+" cm");
        imprimir("Alto  : "+FrmPrincipal.alto3+" cm");
        imprimir("Quemadores    : "+FrmPrincipal.quemadores3);
        imprimir("");
        imprimir("Modelo    : "+FrmPrincipal.modelo4);
        imprimir("Precio    : S/. "+FrmPrincipal.precio4);
        imprimir("Profundidad   : "+FrmPrincipal.fondo4+" cm");
        imprimir("Ancho     : "+FrmPrincipal.ancho4+" cm");
        imprimir("Alto  : "+FrmPrincipal.alto4+" cm");
        imprimir("Quemadores    : "+FrmPrincipal.quemadores4);
 
    }
    private void imprimir(String cad) {
        txtS.append(cad + "\n");
    }
 
}
```

Comment: [checka](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178482/barra-de-desplazamiento)

Comment: SI lo mire , pero lo tengo en always la barra , el problema es al ejecutar me sale como en la foto :/ primero inferior y tengo que subirlo manualmente a la superior

Comment: intenta con txtS .setSelectionStart(0); txtS.setSelectionEnd(0);  despues de ponerle el texto y nos cuentas si funciona

Comment: @RuslanLópez joder macho, eres el mejor muchísimas gracias :D , si quedo bien.

Comment: `txtS.getCaret().setDot(0);` debe servir tambien.